# MSSQL query to retrieve data from DB

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I need data grid in my UI of the following form

```
        | Col1 | Col2 | Col3 | Col4 |
--------------------------------------
        |      |      |      |      |
 Row1   |  10  |  20  |  30  |  40  |
        |      |      |      |      |
 Row2   |  50  |  60  |  70  |  80  |
        |      |      |      |      |
 Row3   |  90  |  100 |  110 |  120 |
        |      |      |      |      |
 Row4   |  130 |  140 |  150 |  160 |
```

The schema of the above DataGrid is stored in the DB as

**Table T1**

```
  ID  |  Description  |   DimensionType
-------------------------------------------
 101  |     Row1     |        1
 102  |     Row2     |        1
 103  |     Row3     |        1
 104  |     Row4     |        1
 105  |     Col1     |        2
 106  |     Col2     |        2
 107  |     Col3     |        2
 108  |     Col4     |        2
```

In the above table `DimensionType` denotes whether the description is row or column. `DimensionType = 1` means `row` and `DimensionType = 2` means `column`.

The values stored in DB are as follows

**Table T2**

```
  ID  |  T1R   |  T1C    |   Value
----------------------------------
 1001 |  101   |   105   |    10
 1002 |  101   |   106   |    20
 1003 |  101   |   107   |    30
 1004 |  101   |   108   |    40
 1005 |  102   |   105   |    50
 1006 |  102   |   106   |    60
 1007 |  102   |   107   |    70
 1008 |  102   |   108   |    80 
 .
 .
 .
 an so on.
```

I wish to retrieve the data in the following form.

```
   Row  |    C1    |  Value  |    C2    |  Value  |    C3    |  Value  |    C4    |  Value  |
 --------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
        |          |         |          |         |          |         |          |         |
   Row1 |   Col1   |    10   |   Col2   |    20   |   Col3   |    30   |   Col4   |    40   |
   Row2 |   Col1   |    50   |   Col2   |    60   |   Col3   |    70   |   Col4   |    80   |
   Row3 |   Col1   |    90   |   Col2   |   100   |   Col3   |   110   |   Col4   |   120   |
   Row4 |   Col1   |   130   |   Col2   |   140   |   Col3   |   150   |   Col4   |   160   |
        |          |         |          |         |          |         |          |         |
```

Need to write a query that can print the data in above format (in MSSQL). If the retrieval can be made further optimized it would be even more helpful, i.e, of the form

```
  Row  |    Col1  |  Col2   |  Col3   |  Col4    |
--------------------------------------------------
       |          |         |         |          |
  Row1 |     10   |    20   |    30   |    40    |
  Row2 |     50   |    60   |    70   |    80    |
  Row3 |     90   |   100   |   110   |   120    |
  Row4 |    130   |   140   |   150   |   160    |
       |          |         |         |          |
```

Thanks in advance!!

Comment: Will there only ever be eight columns or can the columns increase indefinitely? This is just a crosstab challenge and this is usually best solved in the UI, not the database.

Comment: no there can be any number of columns...and the mapping in the UI is not yet done...The result of the UI is to be achieved with the help of the 2 tables.

Comment: I can't see relation between `Row1` and `Col1`. I think the `T2` design isn't right. Instead of this it has to be: `ID  |  T1IDRow | T1IDCol | Value` or something like this.

Comment: i know DB design is shit...But I am not the person responsible for the design and neither am I authorized to question the design. With the given tables I need to achieve the result. Any kind of help will be appreciated!! Thanks!!

Comment: Fine if you don't have access to change in `DATABASE`. Then do it dynamically. 1. Export table in XML. 2. Use parse XML and generate your result.

Comment: In `T1`, Col1 has ID 105. This then has two records in `T2`, with a value of 10 and 50. How do we know which rows these have to appear on? I can't see any relationship between Row1 and 10 and Row2 and 50. How does it work? Do we merely use the order of T2.ID? If so what is the use of the Row data in T1?

Comment: In short the data cannot be retrieved in that form because there is insufficient information in the table to derive it.

Comment: I understand @ElectricLlama...what if `Table T2` is changed slightly (as I have edited)...Then can the result be obtained??

Answer (score 0):

Untested, but try this out (I have no MS SQL in front of me and had not worked in it for at least a year, so this code was written blindly):

```
select t2id, t2t1r, t2t1c, rdesc, 
  STUFF((SELECT ', ' + Value from t ttemp where ttemp.t2t1r = t.t2t1r FOR XML PATH('')), 1, 2, '')  as ConcatenatedValues, 
  STUFF((SELECT ', ' + cdesc from t ttemp where ttemp.t2t1r = t.t2t1r FOR XML PATH('')), 1, 2, '')  as cdescs, 
from
(select T2.ID as t2id, T2.T1R as t2t1r, T2.T1C as t2t1c, Value, row.Description as rdesc, col.Description as cdesc
from T1 join T2 row
on T1.ID = row.T1R and row.DimensionType = 1
join T2 col
on T1.ID = col.T1C and col.DimensionType = 2) t
```